# makefile for a very simple helloworld

Tags: c++, makefile

I am writing my first makefile and it is for a VERY simple helloworld in C++

I am having troubles with this though as this is my first makefile...ever.

What I have thus far is here, I got it online and don't really understand what any of this does and have looked over a lot of makefile tutorials, yet most say I don't need one for a program that is so simple as helloworld. I will paste my code for hello world at the bottom also. Would appreciate any help!! thanks

```
Makefile code: 



TARGET           = hello.exe
OBJECT_01        = hello.o
SOURCE_01        = hello.cpp

$(TARGET): $(OBJECT_01)
         gcc -g -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECT_01) -lstdc++

$(OBJECT_01) : $(SOURCE_01) -o $(OBJECT_01)
         gcc -g -c $(SOURCE_01) -o $(OBJECT_01)

 all : $(TARGET)

 clean :
         -rm $ (TARGET)  $(OBJS)
```

HELLOWORLD CODE:

```
 #include <iostream>

 int main()
   {
     std::cout << "Hello world from me\n ">>
     return 0;
   }
```

Comment: When asking questions please don't say "I am having troubles".  That doesn't mean anything; we all have troubles and StackOverflow is not the place to solve them all.  Say, "I ran command `xyz` and it generated error message `qrst`", where those are cut/paste of the actual command and error message you got, not a paraphrase.

Answer (score 3):

First, change this:

```
$(OBJECT_01) : $(SOURCE_01) -o $(OBJECT_01)
         gcc -g -c $(SOURCE_01) -o $(OBJECT_01)
```

to this:

```
$(OBJECT_01) : $(SOURCE_01)
         gcc -g -c $(SOURCE_01) -o $(OBJECT_01)
```

Second,  change this:

```
std::cout << "Hello world from me\n ">>
```

to this:

```
std::cout << "Hello world from me\n ";
```

Third, this:

```
 clean :
         -rm $ (TARGET)  $(OBJS)
```

to this

```
 clean :
         -rm $(TARGET)  $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Hey that has worked great. I am getting a undefined reference error now though "undefined reference to `std::cout'"

Comment: Then change "gcc" to "g++" in the makefile.
gcc will work out it's c++ based on the file extension but will not link in the c++ libraries by default.

Comment: I changed the gcc to g++ but I still have the same error

Comment: Did you change it in BOTH places (the compile _and_ the link)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably with whitespace.  `make` insists on there being a leading tab characters - ***not*** spaces - before each line associated with a build target (i.e. there should be one tab before each "gcc...", ditto for "-rm..."), and you've indented some of the build targets too: there should be no space before all or clean.  I can't remember if it's actually necessary, but always put a tab after the ':' for each target too.

How to get an actual tab character in to the file is itself interesting on Windows... some editors may seem to "tab over" as you press tab, but are actually injecting enough whitespace to reach the next multiple-of-8 (or whatever width's configured) column: you can often see the difference by using left and right arrow keys to traverse the place where you hope there's a tab, but some editors will simulate moving through spaces so they can replace the tab with spaces and whatever else you start typing.  I recommend you get a resaonable general purpose editor, like the OSS [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which gives sufficient control and visibility into the whole tabs-vs-spaces issue (View menu / Show Symbol / Show White Space And TAB).

The simplest makefile for your needs is just:

```
hello.exe:<tab>hello.cpp
<tab>g++ -g -o hello.exe hello.cpp

clean:
<tab>-rm hello.exe
```

Then just say `make hello.exe` (`make hello` might be enough - give them both a try if you like).

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to mention, I need a clean in it too.